# Esperanto terms and abbreviations for video game terminology

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations

ENGLISH

I am wondering about the conventional Esperanto translations for such gaming-related terms as "hit points", "mana points", "energy points", "free for all", etc. Thus far, I have used "vivpoentoj", "sorĉpoentoj" & "energipoentoj", respectively, but I am curious if these are the forms normally attested, or if there might be other terms used more or at least equally.

Furthermore, I am curious about the abbreviations these terms typically get in English or even internationally (HP, MP, and (less frequently) EP, FFA). Would this be the way to abbreviate them in Esperanto, as well, or is there another, better way? Which way would be most likely to be recognized by Esperantists?

---

ESPERANTO

Mi scivolas pri la kutimaj Esperantaj tradukoj de terminoj rilataj al videoludoj kiel "hit points", "mana points", "energy points", "free for all", ktp. Ĝisnune, mi uzis "vivpoentoj", "sorĉpoentoj" & "energipoentoj" respektive, sed mi scivolas ĉu tiuj estas la kutime uzataj vortoj, aŭ ĉu estas pli aŭ almenaŭ egale uzataj aliaj terminoj.

Plie, mi scivolas pri la oftaj mallongigoj de ĉi tiuj terminoj en la angla aŭ internacie (HP, MP, kaj (malpli ofte) EP, FFA). Ĉu tio estas la maniero mallongigi tiujn ankaŭ en Esperanto, aŭ ĉu estas alia, pli bona maniero? Kiun manieron esperantistoj plej verŝajne rekonus?

Answer (score 3):

This requires an active subculture. Instead of abbreviating Vivopoentoj to Vp or V-pt in the software, one maybe should prefer "Vivo." hit=trafoj, mana=manao.

In fact leaving those English abbreviations untouched might be acceptable, till a game establishes a larger, enthusiast Esperanto community.
*Other smaller languages do the same. And it might shed better light on / be more attractive for Esperanto in the eyes of non-Esperantists.*

You might search for E-o translations of games on Linux.

The gain of proper translations of such terms is comparable to translation of Excel function names. One needs a kind of hybris, and the result is not always that convincing / can lead to confusion.